# Why is load_ps() working on one PC but not on another?

Tags: c, x86, intel, simd, avx

I have written the following code for scaling a set of numbers:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <math.h>
 #include "immintrin.h"

 void scale(struct problem_param prob_param, float* features)
 {
    int i,j,k;
    for (j = 0; j < prob_param.Nr_ft; j++)
    {
        __m256      range_vec ,low_up_vec , low_vec,tmp_vec;
        __m256      feat_min_vec, feat_vec;
        unsigned    count           = prob_param.Size;
        unsigned    offset          = j * prob_param.Size;
        float       feature_max     = features[offset];
        float       feature_min     = features[offset];
        /*
         * Look for min and max of each feature.
         */
        for ( i = 1; i < prob_param.Size ; i++)
        {
            if (features[i + offset] > feature_max )        feature_max = features[i + offset];

            if (features[i + offset] < feature_min )    feature_min = features[i + offset];
        }
        printf("feature : %u \t min = %f \t max = %f \n",j,feature_min,feature_max);
        /*
         * Set the range.
         * Set constant vectors for the vector instructions.
         */
        float       range   = feature_max - feature_min;
        feat_min_vec        = _mm256_set1_ps (feature_min);
        range_vec           = _mm256_set1_ps (range);
        low_up_vec          = _mm256_set1_ps (prob_param.upper_limit - prob_param.lower_limit);
        low_vec             = _mm256_set1_ps (prob_param.lower_limit);
        /*
         * Normalising
         * -----------
         * Head
         */
        for ( i = 0; i < prob_param.Size && count >= 7 ; i+=8)
        {
            feat_vec    = _mm256_load_ps(&features[i + offset]);
            tmp_vec     = _mm256_sub_ps(feat_vec,feat_min_vec);
            tmp_vec     = _mm256_mul_ps(tmp_vec,low_up_vec);
            tmp_vec     = _mm256_div_ps(tmp_vec,range_vec);
            feat_vec    = _mm256_add_ps(tmp_vec,low_vec);

            _mm256_store_ps (&features[i + offset], feat_vec);

            count -=8;
        }
        /*
         * Normalising
         * -----------
         * Tail
         */
        for ( k = i; k < prob_param.Size ; k++)
        {
            features[k + offset] = prob_param.lower_limit + (prob_param.upper_limit - prob_param.lower_limit) * (features[k + offset] - feature_min) / range;
        }
    }
```

this is the function that takes care of the scaling and i call it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "data.h" 
#include "common.h"

#define     training_size       3089
#define     number_features     4
#define     low                 -1.0
#define     up                  1.0
float* feature_array;

int main()
{
  struct problem_param pp;

  pp.Size           =       training_size;
  pp.Nr_ft          =       number_features;
  pp.lower_limit    =       low;
  pp.upper_limit    =       up;

posix_memalign((void **) &feature_array, 32, (size_t) training_size * number_features *sizeof(float));

scale(pp,feature_array);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I tested this code with my MacBook Pro Core i5 Haswell and it works, but when I test it with an ASUS Core I7 Haswell it shows a segmentation fault for the loading. Am I missing something?

Comment: notice that it is not proper to cast `float **` to `void **`. Instead you really should use a temporary `void *` variable.

Comment: I would guess you have a UB urelated to the `load_ps` somewhere...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `offset` (and hence `i + offset`) is not always going to be a multiple of 8 (it's equal to 0, 3089, 6178, 9267 in your above example), so your load and store intrinsics will in general be misaligned.

The simplest solution is to use `_mm256_loadu_ps` in place of `_mm256_load_ps`, and `_mm256_storeu_ps` in place of `_mm256_store_ps`.

As to why this appears to work on your MacBook Pro, my guess is that clang is generating unaligned load/store instructions behind your back, thereby hiding the problem until you try and run the code on a system with a different compiler.

Update: I just verified the above hypothesis by compiling and disassembling the generated code (on a Haswell MacBook Pro with macOS 10.13.4 and Xcode 9.3.1):

```
>>> vmovups (%r14,%r13,4), %ymm0
    vsubps  192(%rsp), %ymm0, %ymm0 ## 32-byte Folded Reload
    vmulps  448(%rsp), %ymm0, %ymm0 ## 32-byte Folded Reload
    vdivps  384(%rsp), %ymm0, %ymm0 ## 32-byte Folded Reload
    vaddps  416(%rsp), %ymm0, %ymm0 ## 32-byte Folded Reload
>>> vmovups %ymm0, (%r14,%r13,4)
```

Note the use of `vmovups` instead of `vmovaps`.